# "Apresentado" é a melhor tradução pra "Featured" ao se referir a recompensas?

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

Acho que vi a primeira *bounty* do nosso SOPT.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E fiquei me perguntando se "apresentado" é a melhor tradução pra esse caso.

Minha sugestão é algo como "recompensado" ou "promovidas" (num sentido mais próximo de *featured*).

Para os interessados na recompensa, a pergunta está [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/342/diferencas-em-grafico-no-matplotlib-para-diferentes-precisoes-de-parametro).

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/353/o-sistema-esta-guardando-estado-onde-nao-deveria

Comment: Já houve [outra pergunta com *bounty*](http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/560/problemas-com-layout-no-zend) antes, e na ocasião também reparei nessa palavra, mas não dei muita importância. Mas concordo que não é a melhor tradução...

Comment: @mgibsonbr e eu querendo ser especial... =P

Answer (score 18):

Acho que fica melhor **destacado** ou **em destaque** nesse contexto. Se não me engano inclusive já foi usado em outros lugares.

Comment: destacado é interessante, mas não passa a idéia de uma recompensa, ou um pagamento para que estejam lá. Parece mais que foi destacado por relevância, pelo administrador. Acredito que 'promovidas' seja mais condizente com o fato de que se coloca rep para bancar uma resposta. Mas seja o que a comunidade decidir...

Comment: *featured* também não passa ideia de recompensa. As perguntas *destacadas* estão lá porque recompensas foram acionadas nelas, mas poderia ser por qualquer motivo mesmo. Em inglês não há essa referência. Até pode-se dar uma tradução livre, mas se quiser manter o espírito do original, não pode pressupor recompensa. Eu acho *promovido* esquisito, não soa bem, mas não me oporia, porque não está errado.

Comment: "Destacado" está correto, mas soa estranho. Que tal "em destaque"?

Comment: @mgibsonbr De fato. Editei. Tinha até pensando nisso, mas acabei deixando o sentido original. Na verdade não sei se todas essas discussões fazem algum sentido. Nós não sabemos o que está acontecendo com elas. Se serão levadas em consideração. Vamos completar 30 dias e não vimos evolução em nada. Nenhum grande problema com isso, o problema é não sabermos o que está acontecendo.

Comment: Creio que "Em destaque" é correto tanto no sentido desejado quanto à tradução literal.

Comment: +1 `"Apresentado"` em PT-BR não faz muito sentido para `featured`. Só se faz em PT-PT, mas não conheço.

Comment: `"Em destaque"`, muito melhor!

Comment: `"Em destaque"` seria perfeito pra ocasião, pelo fato de que o usuário realmente queria destaque na questão ao abrir um Bounty para ela.

Comment: Que tal "Recompensado"?

Comment: Em destaque é tradução correta, e respeita o sentido original. (Realçado é sinônimo, mas nao fica tão bem no contexto)

Comment: "em destaque" me parece propaganda enganosa... a pessoa está querendo uma resposta e está oferecendo uma premiação... "em destaque" sugere algum tipo de mérito, mas no caso quem fez a pergunta está dando pontos de reputação para quem responder... neste sentido "em destaque" é tão irrelevante quanto "apresentado" (e quanto ao original "featured" também.... lembrando que "Aqui NÃO É o stackoverflow.com")

Answer (score 2):

Me ocorreu agora que "Recompensado" pode ser uma boa alternativa.

Sei que não é uma tradução literal do "featured" em inglês, mas atende ao que de fato é a pergunta.

Comment: Recompensada é a resposta (depois da atribuição da recompensa), não a pergunta.

Comment: @bfavaretto metonímia, não? A pergunta pela resposta... faz-se isso em português regularmente...

Comment: reparei agora que "recompensado" vem me recorrendo ao longo do tempo, já que minha memória falha em reter o fato de que já sugeri isso. =P Podem me ignorar aqui.

Comment: Sua referência a metonímia valeu um voto :)

Answer (score 1):

**Não.** “Apresentado” com certeza **não é** a melhor tradução pra “Featured”.

O rótulo "*apresentado*" na *tab* sob "Perguntas" não faz o menor sentido.

Eu **não sei** qual seria a melhor tradução. Não é fácil determinar. Posso apresentar algumas sugestões (incluindo na lista as demais *apresentadas* aqui):

- disputadas
- especiais
- destacadas
- em destaque
- promovidas
- com recompensa
- com bônus
- bonificadas
- com premiação
- bônus

Eu particularmente prefiro "**com recompensa**" porque passa ao novato a informação precisa e incontroversa do que realmente significa.

Na minha opinião, qualquer opção da lista acima, mesmo que seja escolhida aleatoriamente,  sem dúvida fica melhor que "*apresentado*".

Comment: Concordo com a última frase, essa tradução ruim já durou mais do que devia.